# Special Character # in a string

Tags: java, string, special-characters

I have a string tmp which is as follows

```
  <a href="#" class="quickLinks" id="linkQL">Quick Links</a>
```

I would like to be able to know that there is a # after href= .. I thought of doing it this way if (tmp.indexOf('#') == 8) but I am not able to , I think its because # is a special character

Comment: This sounds like a good match for regular expressions. And, by the way, there's nothing special about `#` in Java string literals.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to"? tmp.indexOf('#') should return 9.

Comment: If you literally  want to just check that the string `#` comes anywhere after the `href` string (e.g. in a `id` attribute after the href), then you could use a regex. If you want to check if `#` is in the `href` attribute, then you should use a html parser.

Answer (score 1):

To test if # follows href, you can simply to this:

```
if (input.contains("href=\"#\""))
```

There is no need to involve regex, and the hash char # is not special in java, but the double quote chars need escaping.

Comment: Single quotes are valid html, or at least supported by browsers. I guess it depends where the html comes from how confident you are with how it will look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the `href` attribute contains a `#`, then use a HTML parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String href = doc.select("a").first().attr("href");
boolean isHash = href.equals("#");
```

If you really want to just check if the there is a `#` anywhere on the line after a `href`, you could use [Regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - but I suspect that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`var tmp = '<a href="#" class="quickLinks" id="linkQL">Quick Links</a>';`
`tmp.indexOf('#');` 
 This is returning 9 and it is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try regex

```
boolean matches = s.matches(".+href\\s*=\\s*['\"]#['\"].+");
```